# c# - write class name,class methods and class properties to text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, properties, methods

Just like in the title. How to get class name, class properties and class methods ? There is an easy way for that ? I'm trying to build program that draw (using latex) class diagram - thats why i need class name, properties and methods. Do i have to use Regex to parse class file and get all content (properties,methods) or there is an easier way ? ;)

Maybe you got some suggestion how to achieve this.

Comment: you will have to use reflection and retrieve the names from the class

Answer (score 1):

Reflection. Start with a `Type` instance, either from `typeof(T)` or from `obj.GetType()` - that gives you everything you need for a runtime type, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.Name);
}
```

There are similar methods for events, fields, constructors, methods, etc.

Comment: This is without a doubt the way to go. If you have never touched reflection before it might seem a bit voodoo-like, but it quickly becomes second nature to you, and opens up entirely new avenues of problem solving in .NET - including elimination of of repetitive code when working with objects that contain a lot of methods/properties.

Comment: Thx :). But how to get that from a .cs file. I dont want to call an instance of this class - all i got is path to .cs file. How to pass .cs file location and then get methods,props and other info from it ?

Comment: There is no chance to get that form a .cs file ? The only way to refer to a class is to refer to its dll file ? But where there is a dll file after compilation ?

Comment: @born2fr4g if you are processing from .cs, then ... you'll either have to parse the file, or maybe the new "comiler-as-a-service" stuff in .NET 4.5 is the way to go with this? that should (as I understand it) have code designed to help with that. But I haven't played with that yet.

Comment: Parsing file with Regex is not that bad ;). Thx for you opinion. One more, general question:to create class diagram what i need from project files ? .cs files (all classes) thats all i need ? Or i need additional files (like dlls or something ?) im talking about ASP.NET site.